# Data loss in UDP socket due to different connection speed between Client and server i

Tags: c#, udp, loss

I m working on a project for sending some big size object throw UDP protocol (written in C#), all works well. The problem is that there is a difference in connection speed between the Client and Server that causing a loss of about 70 % of the packets. The solution that I m working on is to put a sleep while sending the packets to slow down the emission process. For that I want to know if there is any methods for getting the optimal sleeping time between two consecutive emissions because I need to have the maximum possible speed.
If you need more details, just ask.

Comment: Any process that requires 100% delivery is a bad choice for UDP.  Use TCP instead.

Comment: It doesn t require 100%, but just to minimise loss.
And I don t have the choice, I have to use UDP.
This is my question : 
"For that I want to know if ther is any methodes for getting the optimal sleeping time between two consicutives emissions because I need to have the maximum possible speed"